# Getting error when trying to install R Package "Tidytext"

Tags: tidytext

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidytext’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
>       6.
>       stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
>       5.
>       value[3L]
>       4.
>       tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
>       3.
>       tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
>       2.
>       tryCatch({ attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc) env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps) ...
>       1.
>       library(tidytext)

---

upon running

```
tidyverse:::tidyverse_attach()
tidyverse:::tidyverse_conflicts()

> tidyverse:::tidyverse_attach()
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
> tidyverse:::tidyverse_conflicts()
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `install.packages('stringi')`

See this issue thread for more details: https://github.com/bvieth/powsimR/issues/20

I personally found that when my OS updates R, all of my downloaded packages get broken in some weird way. I've yet to find a fix for it.